# Pandas Regex pattern some cleaning required

Tags: python, regex

I have an input text :

```
text = '146.204.224.152 - feest6811 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:24 -0700] "POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1" 302 4622\n197.109.77.178 - kertzmann3129 [21/Jun/2019:15:45:25 -0700] "DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0" 203 26554\n156.127.178.177 - [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700] "DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1

output Required :['feest6811','kertzmann3129','-']

output getting :[ ' feest6811', ' kertzmann3129',' ']
```

Below is the code used

```
user_name = re.findall('(?<=[-])\s[a-zA-Z0-9]*',text)
```

Second output Required :

```
['POST /incentivize HTTP/1.1','DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.0','DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.1']

Output getting :
['POST /incentivize HTTP/1.','DELETE /virtual/solutions/target/web+services HTTP/2.','DELETE /interactive/transparent/niches/revolutionize HTTP/1.']
```

Below is the code used for the above second output

```
request =  re.findall('[a-zA-Z]*\s/[a-zA-Z].*[.\+]',text)
```

So as you can see there is small thing that i'm missing in both output 1 and 2

in output 1 i'm missing '-' signs when we have no data and in second output i'm not able to read the last word after '.'

Can anyone recommend the necessary changes to the code..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first, you need a slight adjustment. You need to but the `\s` with the lookbehind

```
user_name = re.findall('(?<=[-]\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]*', text)
print(user_name)
```

But this will produce:

```
['feest6811', 'kertzmann3129', '']
```

There is no way you can get '-' as the third value of the returned list since lookbehind is never part of the match. This third `-`  in the input string that you wanted in the final `findall` match is in the following context:

```
156.127.178.177 - [21/Jun/2019:15:45:27 -0700]
```

The regex, which returns a '' in this case, is just as good an indicator that the '-' is present in the input string with a corresponding empty `[a-zA-Z0-9]*` subexpression match. If it really bothers you, you can always do:

```
user_name = re.findall('(?<=[-]\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]*', text)
user_name = ['-' if x == '' else x for x in user_name] # convert '' to '-'
print(user_name)
```

Prints:

```
['feest6811', 'kertzmann3129', '-']
```

For the second one use:

```
request =  re.findall(r'[a-zA-Z]*\s/[a-zA-Z].*?/\d\.\d', text)
```

Answer (score 3):

For the first pattern you can use an alternation to match the `-` if what is on the right is a space and `[` using a positive lookahead.

```
(?<=-\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+|-(?= \[)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vPOMJR/1)

---

For the second pattern you can make the match a bit more specific and extend it as necessary.

```
(?:POST|DELETE) \S+ HTTP/(?:1\.[01]|2.0)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/dUiJo4/1)

Or a bit more broader match using a capturing group which would be returned by re.findall, and match the uppercase chars  followed by `/` and a char a-zA-Z right after the opening double quotes.

Not sure if the last `"` is missing, but in that case you can either match it or assert the end of the string.

```
"([A-Z]+\s/[a-zA-Z][^"]+)(?:"|$)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ObtZbS/1)

---

See this [Python demo](https://ideone.com/XUHeCN) with the results for all 3 patterns.

Answer (score 1):

I like to use Regex101.com to build regexes like this.

Please try the following

1.Here is the corrected version: https://regex101.com/r/bFDnSm/2

Note the regex changed to

> (?<=[-]\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]*

2. Here is the corrected version:
   https://regex101.com/r/4uLVUb/1

Note the regex changed to:

> [a-zA-Z]*\s/[a-zA-Z+/]+\s[A-Z]+/[0-9.]+

You should find this is quite broad and should work even with further examples.